# show multiple content in one page in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to show the multiple content in one page in asp.net. For example, I have create a menu and in that I have one category option in that subcategory in that subcategory1 and so on. Flow like, [image]

Here, in image you can see menu show 1 category joins the 4 types of subcategory.
i.e. Business Product(category) => Business Standard(subcategory) => Envelopes(subcategory) => Long Business(subcategory) => Standard Envelopes(subcategory).

So, all these four menu contains the four different pages. lets the name is business.aspx, businessstandard.aspx, envelops.aspx, longbusiness.aspx and standardenvelopes.aspx.

Now, my purpose is that I want to show these multiple page in one page only. Let give that one page is default.aspx.

Because in future if more than 4 category is there then I don't want to make the regarding their page. There content shows in default page.

So, I want to make the dynamic content for the multiple menu in one page.

So, is it possible to do this? If yes then please provide me information to complete this task.

Awaiting for your reply.

Advance in Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried master page concepts? AFAIK, master pages capable to hold multiple pages in a single layout, depending how you put `ContentPlaceHolder` on it.

Comment: Have you thought about `iframe`s (more html way) or `UserControls` (more asp.net way)?

Comment: Thank you for the comment @TetsuyaYamamoto, but if admin add 5 submenu then how can I manage it. Because I have create only 4 submenu page?

Comment: Thank you for the comment @MikhailNeofitov, can you prefer me any link regarding this topic. So that I can understandable more better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is possible way.

Please go through Asp Mutliview concepts. You can have n number of views within one single page.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247215.aspx

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But Shubham, let suppose I have add the four view for the four subcategories. But if tomorrow admin had added one more subcategories then at that time I want add the one more view?

Comment: Yes. You need to add one more view under same Mutliview. This comes under "State Management" concepts of Asp.Net. I hope this helped you.